# Embed a UIViewController in a NavigationController using segues

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uistoryboard, uistoryboardsegue

I have a viewController that is *usually* (most often) accessed by using a push segue. This viewController needs to be embedded in a UINavigationController. So typically, this is no problem. The push segue manages pushing the viewController, and therefore the viewController has it's UINavigationController.

My issue is that in a few cases, I'd like to present this same exact viewController using a modal segue. When I do this, the viewController is not embedded in a navigationController. Is there a way to do this using segues?

I know this can be done purely in code without segues by creating a UINavigationController, setting the rootView as the viewController and then presenting that modally. That can be done using code like this :

```
MyViewController *viewController = [[MyViewController alloc] init];
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController];
[self presentModalViewController:navController animated:YES];
```

But how do I do this same thing but using Segues?

### Update

---

For further clarity, here is some code to supplement how I used the accepted answer in the prepareForSegue method.

**When Using Modal Segue**

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue destinationViewController] isEqualToString:@"Modal to MyVC"])
    {
        UINavigationController *nav = [segue destinationViewController];
        MyViewController *vc = [nav topViewController];
        //setup vc
    }
}
```

**When Using Push Segue**

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue destinationViewController] isEqualToString:@"Push to MyVC"])
    {
        MyViewController *vc = [segue destinationViewController];
        //setup vc
    }
}
```

Comment: This works great! Was stuck up using modal segues and this helped me out.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

In your Storyboard, you can embed a ViewController in a Navigation Controller by selecting the View Controller and then picking from the menu at the top `Editor->Embed In->Navigation Controller`.  From another view controller, you control drag to this Navigation controller to set up the `modal` segue.  You can also control drag to the original View Controller to set up segues to it without the Navigation Controller.

[image: Storyboard showing a view controller both embedded in a navigation controller and not]