# Missing navigation in master-detail application with two table controllers

Tags: ios, swift

I'm working on `Master-Detail Application` (`Swift`) with two `UITableViewController`'s as master and detail.

When I click cell in `master`, I'm redirected to `detail`, this part works as expected, but in `details` view I don't see navigation bar, which is a problem.

**Question**

How can I show navigation in `detail` view ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select each Table View Controller in the Story Board, then go to `Editor` => `Embed in` => `Navigation Controller`. If you do this for each `detail` view, you should be able to see the navigation bar appear.

Also, have you taken a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16254273/2730985
from [Embed a UIViewController in a NavigationController using segues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16253631/embed-a-uiviewcontroller-in-a-navigationcontroller-using-segues)?

Comment: That worked great @Jake, thanks a lot. Another lesson learned :)