# Why is button and title not showing up on navigation bar when I add them programmatically?

Tags: swift, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem, navigationbar

I tried to make a navigation bar programmatically with a button and title. For some reason, the navigation bar shows up, but the button and title does not. How do you fix this?

```
    // Create the navigation bar
    let navigationBar = UINavigationBar(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 500, 200))

    //Create navigation bar's title
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.title = "Edit"

    //Create back button
    let backBtn = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.Custom)
    let backButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: backBtn)
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButtonItem

    //Add navigation bar to view
    self.view.addSubview(navigationBar)
```

Comment: why don't you ember your viewcontroller into navigationcontroller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For you question,since you didn't embeded viewcontroller to a navigationcontroller, so all your settings made no sense

```
self.navigationController? = nil & 
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem //there's no navigationcontroller made no sense
```

what you need to do is,embeded vc to navigationcontroller in proper time like

```
let navVC = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
```

and then u could navigationController and set all stuffs

Comment: I tried to follow your advice.  I assigned 'ViewController' as a navigation controller in my AppDelegate (b/c in my app, there's a view controller called 'ViewController' that connects to the 'editViewController'), but I still get an error.

Comment: @Amanda error with what? then's several ways to embed vc in a NavigationController , maybe u ref [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16253631/embed-a-uiviewcontroller-in-a-navigationcontroller-using-segues)  to correct