# How to embed UINavigationController to UITableViewController In Xamarin iOS

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, uistoryboard

Good day,

I am have worked the last 6 months on the Android side of my application, and I have now started on the iOS side.

I am using Xamarin C# in Visual Studio 2015 Update 2 with a Macbook Pro as a build and design  server.

I am totally new to iOS Development

I have read quite a few articles regarding my question, but none seem to answer my question in its entirety, or I am just too green to understand them.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

What I am trying to do is to display a UITableViewController for each cell of a tableview with STATIC cells that a user clicks on. In order to display the icons and text, I had to go with Static cells, and therefore with a UITableViewController instead of a normal UIViewController based on the static cells that requires the UITableViewController.

My Storyboard is as follows:

[My Storyboard Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TolXt.png)

1. Initial view controller - UiViewController with a Container View.
2. In the Container View is embedded the first UITableViewCOntroller which houses my TableView with static cells for the menu.
3. When a user clicks on a cell, I now want to display UITableViewController number 2.

My question is as follows:
How to I embed a UINavigationController to the first UITableViewController in order to facilitate navigation between the main menu and the subsequent ViewControllers that each option should display?

EDIT: My question is fundementally the same as some solutions provided here but with the difference that I am using Visual Studio and Xamarin. The solutions provided here do not show how to solve this with segues in Visual Studio and the code is also provided in Objective-C and I am working in C#.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Embed a UIViewController in a NavigationController using segues](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16253631/embed-a-uiviewcontroller-in-a-navigationcontroller-using-segues)

Comment: Almost, but what you are referring to looks to be in Objective-C. Also, How do you go Editor->Embed In->Navigation Controller in Visual Studio? If you can tell me how to do that, then the problem is solved.

Comment: Also, will 1 UINavigationController suffice or do I need to have one between the 1st UITableVIewController and EACH subsequent UITableViewController that will be displayed?

Answer (score 0):

This question looks like it has a possible solution as mentioned by haider_kazal, but it is not the same if you look under the skin. The possible answer mentioned here refers to the normal way of having a Navigation Controller and setting a root View Controller.

This question is different in the sense that you are dealing with a View Controller, that has a TableView with static cells EMBEDDED into it by means of a Container View. With this setup, when you try to specify a root controller, the Navigation bar does not appear on the root view controller. So far the answer for this problem seems to be that there is no clear answer.