# Value of type 'UITableView' has no member 'navigationController' swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have custom UITableView Class and on `didSelectRowAt` want to move on next controller but this error occur how can resolve it?

Comment: Can you add the code, please?

Comment: Your `tableView` won't have navigationController. Try `self.navigationController` where `self` will refer to your `UIViewController` or `UITableViewController`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16253631/embed-a-uiviewcontroller-in-a-navigationcontroller-using-segues

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your not showing any code I have to guess from your headline.

A view or UITableView in fact really has no member navigationController.

A UIViewController or UITableViewController has such member.

Maybe you mixed view and view controller ?

Answer (score 0):

Viewcontrollers can have a navigation controller, did you mean UITableViewController?